# Image recognition for tests

Tags: java, android, image-recognition

Let's say I'm a teacher(I'm not) and I have tests which I give to my students on paper for them to solve. The tests are simple yes/no questions and have a separate paper for answers. Let's say I want an app that can recognize the test from a photo and check (you give the app the photo and it tells you your score). Is this possible and how complex will it be? I read a little about Image recognition and found some articles, but they mainly focus on recognizing images (yes this is the image/no this is not the image) and not patterns.

Comment: @Takendarkk That I am fully aware of. I am asking to get an idea what is needed and on that base decide if I have the time (and interest) to dig deeper in.

Comment: Take a look at the OpenCV library.